# Como recompilar todas as Views, procedures e triggers no Firebird?

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, trigger

Preciso recompilar todas as Views, procedures e triggers no Firebird, não pelo IBExpert, mas sim pelo Delphi XE2, irei passar um SQL, gostaria de saber como realizar tal procedimento.

Comment: Não há recompilação em SQL. O que você pode fazer é recriar todas as Views, procedures e triggers do seu BD. Talvez seu problema não seja exatamente esse, e você deveria esclarecer melhor o que você está tentando obter.

Comment: Sim eu gostaria de recriar, porém gostaria de saber se tem algum comando que eu possa realizar pelo Delphi para tal procedimento, pois pelo IBExpert eu seu realizar, gostaria de deixar uma função no sistema caso seja possivel.

Comment: Basta pegar o SQL gerado no IBExpert e enviar ele como script no Delphi. Mas sinceramente não faz sentido... Você não deveria precisar fazer isso.